# Ubuntu 18.04 gnome high CPU usage

Tags: nvidia, gnome, graphics, 18.04, gnome-shell

**Introduction**

Hi.

I'm new to Linux (literally I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 two days ago).

**Question**

I'm curios about high CPU usage by `gnome-shell`. I just need to move a mouse to load four cores of my Intel Core i5 about 20-30%. It's weird. Does anyone know what to do and what to check?

**Proof**
[image]

**Details**

- I think that gnome render itself through CPU and ignore my video card.
- I disabled `secure boot`.
- I've installed NVIDIA proprietary drivers. Version 390.77.
- I'm using NVIDIA PRIME profile.
- I rebooted couple times.
- I definitely tried to find a solution myself.

**Tech details**

`lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [103c:18fd]
    Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] [10de:1140] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GeForce GT 630M [103c:18fd]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

`nvidia-smi` output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.77                 Driver Version: 390.77                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 630M     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   53C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    469MiB /  1985MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`prime-select query` output:
`nvidia`

Comment: What's the problem with this? The load average is perfectly fine, meaning your system is way within its limits.

Comment: Is it ok that moving a mouse loads my CPU so much? Or am I incorrectly reading `htop`?

Comment: While I don't believe your CPU usage should be *that* high when moving your mouse, it does not appear to be affecting your system. You have a quad core system, so as long as the load average is under 4.0, you're fine.